# Conditional checkbox and active field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i'm create a plugin and i've add some field. I need to make active this custom field only user select a checkbox.

I do this

```
<?php
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />';
echo '<div id="mycheckboxdiv" style="display:none">';

              woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => "_bulkdiscount_quantity_$i", 'label' => __( 'Quantity (min.)', 'wc_bulk_discount' ), 'type' => 'number', 'description' => __( 'Enter the minimal quantity below apply the discount', 'wc_bulk_discount' ), 'custom_attributes' => array(
                                'step' => '1',
                                'min' => '1'
                            ) ) );
                            woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => "_bulkdiscount_discount_$i", 'type' => 'number', 'label' => __( 'Discount (%)', 'wc_bulk_discount' ), 'description' => __( 'Enter the discount in percents', 'wc_bulk_discount' ), 'custom_attributes' => array(
                                    'step' => 'any',
                                    'min' => '0',
                                    'max' => '100'
                                ) ) );
              echo '</div>';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
        $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

But if i select checkbox my field not appear. Where i wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript looks fine. Working example is attached. Do you have jQuery setup on the page?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
<div id="mycheckboxdiv" style="display:none">
  Content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
         $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok now work. I not insert the jquery. Is possible to use this for multiple field?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple fields?

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress, jQuery needs to be referenced as `jQuery`, not `$`. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
        jQuery('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

An alternative is to use a [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and thus define `$` as `jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
            $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
        });
    });

})(jQuery)

</script>
```